# Pandoc Syntax Highlighting in PDF not working

Tags: python, pdf, latex, syntax-highlighting, pandoc

`pandoc --version` yields:

```
pandoc 1.12.2.1
Compiled with texmath 0.6.5.2, highlighting-kate 0.5.5.1.
Syntax highlighting is supported for the following languages:
    actionscript, ada, apache, asn1, asp, awk, bash, bibtex, boo, c, changelog, clojure, cmake, coffee, coldfusion, commonlisp, cpp, cs, css, curry, d, diff, djangotemplate, doxygen, doxygenlua, dtd, eiffel, email, erlang, fortran, fsharp, gnuassembler, go, haskell, haxe, html, ini, java, javadoc, javascript, json, jsp, julia, latex, lex, literatecurry, literatehaskell, lua, makefile, mandoc, markdown, matlab, maxima, metafont, mips, modelines, modula2, modula3, monobasic, nasm, noweb, objectivec, objectivecpp, ocaml, octave, pascal, perl, php, pike, postscript, prolog, python, r, relaxngcompact, rhtml, roff, ruby, rust, scala, scheme, sci, sed, sgml, sql, sqlmysql, sqlpostgresql, tcl, texinfo, verilog, vhdl, xml, xorg, xslt, xul, yacc, yaml
Default user data directory: /home/xiaolong/.pandoc
Copyright (C) 2006-2013 John MacFarlane
Web:  http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is no
warranty, not even for merchantability or fitness for a particular purpose.
```

I am trying the following:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
```python
Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Oct 19 2015, 21:52:17)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random  # seed is determined here, if not set by the developer themself
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
50
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
62
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
53
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
17
>>> random.seed("I am a hashable object.")
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
41
>>> random.seed("I am a hashable object.")
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
41
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
88
>>> random.seed("I am a hashable object.")
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
41
>>> random.randint(0, 100)
88
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

The command to compile my PDF I use is:

```
pandoc --read=markdown --table-of-contents --toc-depth=2 --preserve-tabs --standalone --template=template.latex --latex-engine=xelatex Hausarbeit.md --highlight-style=pygments -o Hausarbeit.pdf
```

This is code I have in my `template.latex`:

```
$if(highlighting-macros)$
$highlighting-macros$
$endif$
$if(verbatim-in-note)$
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
$endif$
```

According to the Pandoc documentation [Pandoc documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#fenced-code-blocks) this should result in highlighted text for the Python language. However, everything in that code block only becomes monospace and no colors are applied.

What's more is, that there is an error when compiling:

```
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source.
! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

\GenericError  ...                                
                                                  \endgroup 
l.200 \begin{Shaded}
```

My guess is, that there is something missing in the template to define `Shaded`. I even installed some package of `highlighting-kate` named `libghc-highlighting-kate-dev`, because I read somewhere, that this is what pandoc uses, but to no avail, the text stays black.

How do I get the syntax highlighting working?

**EDIT#1**

That error did not appear, when I simply indented the code to use standard markdown syntax for code. But in that case I'll not have any syntax highlighting per se.

**EDIT#2**

The tags "PDF", "Python" and "syntax-highlighting" are indeed related, since this is specifically about creating a PDF file and specifically about syntax highlighting. Also it could be that there is only a problem with highlighting python code in the created PDF files, so the python tag is also related. Please read the question before concluding too quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to add `--listings` option to your pandoc compile command:

```
pandoc --read=markdown --table-of-contents --toc-depth=2 --preserve-tabs --standalone --template=template.latex --latex-engine=xelatex --listings Hausarbeit.md --highlight-style=pygments -o Hausarbeit.pdf
```

Comment: Thank You! I had the same issue in R trying to get Pandoc to generate a PDF from a custom LaTeX template.  **This solution worked for me.**  R uses the `knitr` package as a Pandoc interface - @Yihui (the creator of the `knitr` package) notes [here](http://yihui.name/knitr/) that code highlighting is accomplished via the `framed` LaTeX package.  Perhaps this could be helpful to those using Python.

Comment: This is needed, but also the packages `textcomp` and `xcolor` apparently.