# How to highlight code using R exams to pdf function

Tags: r, r-exams

I want to create an R/exams exercise (in PDF format) where the R code is highlighted. I tried to use the `highlight=TRUE` option in the code chunk, but it produced an error when I tried to generate the PDF with the `exams::exams2pdf` function.

Using the following example exercise (i.e., `example.Rmd`):

````
Question
========
Some question with code:

```{r echo=TRUE, warning=FALSE, eval=FALSE, highlight=TRUE}
library("blavaan")
HS.model <- 'visual =~ x1 + prior("normal(1,1)")*x2 + x3
             verbal =~ x4 + x5 + x6 '

bfit <- bcfa(model = HS.model,
             data = HolzingerSwineford1939,
             dp = dpriors(lambda = "normal(1,5)"),
             burnin = 500,
             sample = 500,
             n.chains = 4)
```

Meta-information
================
exname: some_ex_name
extype: string
exsolution: nil
````

When I try:

```
exams::exams2pdf("example.Rmd")
```

it trows an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.
```

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41052687/rstudio-pdf-knit-fails-with-environment-shaded-undefined-error,  or reinstall tinytex `tinytex::reinstall_tinytex()`

Comment: So I did it. No success, the same error keeps appearing.

Comment: I simplified the exercise because previously the `pts` variable was not defined. Also SO formatting tip: If you want to show Markdown code verbatim, it's easiest to use a four-space indent, then the backticks are shown without extra "tricks". To get the indenting you can just hightlight the code and press Ctrl-G.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that formatting tip. It makes life much easier when posting r exams questions with Rmd code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `exams2pdf()` function embeds the exercises into a master LaTeX template, by default `plain.tex`. As this does not provide the LaTeX `{Shaded}` environment that `knitr` will produce for chunks with `highlight = TRUE` you get the error.

The solution is to use a template that includes a suitable environment. To demonstrate how this works, R/exams ships the `plain-highlight.tex` template. I recommend you adapt this into your own template that you use.

With the demo template your example works:

```
exams2pdf("example.Rmd", template = "plain-highlight")
```

[image: Example exercise compiled with exams2pdf and plain-highlight.tex LaTeX template]

Comment: It worked only on my Windows machine, not working on Linux. Do you know why? https://i.imgur.com/G5WP6TZ.png

Comment: Not sure. It's not a general Linux issue because my output was generated on Debian GNU/Linux. To debug, please try: `exams2pdf("example.Rmd", template = "plain-highlight", texdir = "debug-tex")`. The resulting directory "debug-tex" should have three files: `exercise1.tex`, `plain-highlight1.pdf`, `plain-highlight1.tex`.Then you can try to run these with your standard TeX engine to see whether they work as intended.

Comment: Great! Solved. By the way, do you recommend any code highlight style to use with printed pdf? Cheers, Achim!

Comment: This solution is working for the exams2pdf function. But for the exams2nops I am getting an error. With:

`exams::exams2nops(file="example.Rmd",template = "plain-highlight")`

I get:

`Error in exams2pdf(file, n = n, nsamp = nsamp, dir = dir, name = name,  : 
  formal argument "template" matched by multiple actual arguments`

With:

`exams::exams2nops(file="example.Rmd")`

I get:

`! LaTeX Error: Environment Shaded undefined.`

To avoid opening a new question I just add this comment. If you prefer I can create a new question.

Comment: The only way to make it work was inserting the:
`header = "\\usepackage{framed}`
`...`
`\\providecommand{\\tightlist}{\\setlength{\\itemsep}{0pt}\\setlength{\\parskip}{0pt}}"`

Comment: Yes, `exams2nops()` doesn't have a highlight option, yet, and you have to insert the style manually via the `header` or a custom `usepackage` or something along those lines. Personally, I would not recommend to use color highlighting of code in printed exams. I can understand the color highlighting for e-exams, that makes sense, but for printing I think it's not ideal.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. If the exams are printed in color it might be nice to have code highlight.

Comment: Personally, I still think that it is a waste of resources. But, of course, your mileage may vary... and that's OK.

Comment: Yeah, but for a few post-graduation students with lots of items with code, it can help. Nevertheless, thank you ever so much for helping me to understand the flexibility of the package.